# Does the Facebook all.js need to be included before any <fb:like> for IE 8?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-like

The Facebook Like button all of a sudden stopped working in IE 8.  And reducing the code shows that it seems like IE 8 requires the `all.js` of Facebook be included before any `<fb:like>` tags?

This is not required in Chrome or Firefox, or even IE 9.   Is it true?  I thought there might be one point I put it before the `js` and it worked too?  Does anyone know or have this experience previously?

Answer (score 0):

You want to load all.js early but it can be done asynchronously.  Using the best practice from Facebook, loading all.js can be done this way:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: '...',
        xfbml: true
      });
    };

    (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.async = true;
      e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
```

More detail at the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)